# iphone racing game in cocos3d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos3d

I am working on iPhone racing car game development using cocos3d.In this how can I get detection of boundaries of road in road-map.I have done with load pod file for road-map.I also want to know about how can I implement physics for car accident.Is their any sample code of game from which I get some information or tutorial which I can follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you, I use [Unity](http://unity3d.com). Check out their [Car Tutorial](http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/car-tutorial) that's what you need.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There are very few examples and tutorials available for Cocos3D at the moment. Definitely nothing that fits your bill.

Your project sounds like a lot of pioneering you need to do. Particularly physics will be an issue, because both Box2D and Chipmunk are 2D physics engines. You'll need to find an iOS compatible, open source 3D physics engine. I like [ODE](http://www.ode.org/), and I've heard good things about [Newton](http://www.geeks3d.com/20110218/newton-game-dynamics-physics-engine-now-open-source/) too. I don't know if they're compatible with iOS though.

To add collision shapes to your POD files would also be a manual process requiring (self-made) tools or a lot of sweat.